# DropDownList automatically closes in Firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox

I have several forms in ASP.Net MVC.

I noticed that some of the dropdowns close automatically in FireFox, but not in IE.

I don't have any Javascript or JQuery with triggered actions on any of these dropdowns.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

```
<form action="Index" id="MyID" method="get"><label>
Search&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="searchWord" name="searchWord" type="text" value="" />
&nbsp; &nbsp;Category <select id="CategoryID" name="CategoryID"><option value="">-- Select All --</option>
<option value="1">Item A</option>
<option value="2">Item B</option>
<option value="3">Item C</option>
<option value="4">Item D</option>
<option value="5">Item E</option>
</select>
</label>
<label>
<input class="button" value="Search" type="submit" />
</label>
</form>
```

The dropdown list is coded using Razor as:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", "-- Select All --")
```

Comment: For more on DropDownList, see my tutorial Working with the DropDownList Box and jQuery (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc ) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<label>` tag defines a label. You have wrong close tag for `<label>`.

Comment: Unbelievable.  I had a single <label> tag wrapped around 3 select lists and the last 2 were always closing as soon as they'd opened.  I'd have never spotted this poor markup if it wasn't for your answer.  Thanks.